# Añadir a elemnto <li> de un menú una linea debajo con un punto

Tags: html, css, menú

tengo el problema de que debo hacer el menu con un punto antes de una linea en un elemento li, como en la foto que os dejo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe si esto se puede hacer?. Vamos la linea si, pero el punto antes?.....es que no me viene a la cabeza como

Un saludo

Comment: Por favor, podrías agregar tu HTML y CSS?  Así vemos cómo modificarlo.

Comment: ¿Lo has visto en alguna página o solo en imagen? Inspeccionando el HTML puedes ver como lo hicieron

Comment: Hay muchas formas, con css, con imagenes, etc..

Comment: Ojala lo hubiera visto..me ahorraba preguntar....pero me llego la persona con esto....y me quede en blanco...mira que le he dado vuelta. Esa imagen es sacada de un pdf que me dieron...

Comment: Si te ha servido mi respuesta más abajo, por favor, marcala como solucionada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una solucion "poco elegante" pero funcional, espero que te sirva

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
li{ 
  display: inline-block; 
  padding: 5px 10px; 
}
.text{ 
  width:100%; 
  padding:0; 
  color: #0F84FF;
  margin: 5px auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.dot{ 
  width: 3px; 
  height: 3px; 
  float:left; 
  border-radius: 100%; 
  background:#FFB61D; 
  position:relative; 
}
.sub{ 
  width: calc(100% - 10px); 
  margin-left: 10px; 
  height: 2px; 
  background:#0F84FF;
  position:relative; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> 
<p class="text">Home</p> 
<div class="dot"></div> 
<div class="sub"></div> 
  </li> 

  <li> 
<p class="text">Product</p> 
<div class="dot"></div> 
<div class="sub"></div> 
  </li> 

 <li> 
<p class="text">Contact with us</p> 
<div class="dot"></div> 
<div class="sub"></div> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Buenas telef. Solo podemos dejarle comentarios y esperar a que él la acepte. No se puede hacer más. Respecto a tu respuesta, has de explicar mejor como funciona tu codigo ya que tal y como está solo sirve para copiar y pegar, no entender. Evita en el futuro responder a preguntas de baja calidad que no muestran intentos o explicacion detallada. Un saludo